# Are there any existing algorithms to measure the readability of text and background colors?

Tags: color-scheme, color-perception, algorithm

Are there existing algorithms that can measure readability colors for text over a background? (on-screen text for e.g.).

Something which could be used (for example) for auto-generating color schemes that don't produce unreadable text.

While I wouldn't mind writing my own, it seems like something there may be existing tried & true solutions for.

A simple algorithm could calculate a readability score that would be lowered when:

- Colors have the same "brightness".
- Saturated colors are far apart on the color wheel
  (opposite colors or approaching opposite). Red-on-green for example.
- De-saturated text over bright background colors might also need to be accounted for.

Further I would need to try this to see how well it works.

Are there existing methods in common use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find this in the W3 Accessibility Recommendations under the title "[**Relative Luminance**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#relativeluminancedef)". The formula is as follows, but I recommend you look it up in the original link, as the text here has a strange format, so I am just including it just for reference:

> the relative brightness of any point in a colorspace, normalized to 0
> for darkest black and 1 for lightest white
>
> Note 1: For the sRGB colorspace, the relative luminance of a color is
> defined as L = 0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B where R, G and B
> are defined as:
>
> ```
> if RsRGB <= 0.03928 then R = RsRGB/12.92 else R = ((RsRGB+0.055)/1.055) ^ 2.4
>
> if GsRGB <= 0.03928 then G = GsRGB/12.92 else G = ((GsRGB+0.055)/1.055) ^ 2.4
>
> if BsRGB <= 0.03928 then B = BsRGB/12.92 else B = ((BsRGB+0.055)/1.055) ^ 2.4
> ```
>
> and RsRGB, GsRGB, and BsRGB are defined as:
>
> ```
> RsRGB = R8bit/255
>
> GsRGB = G8bit/255
>
> BsRGB = B8bit/255
> ```
>
> The "^" character is the exponentiation operator. (Formula taken from
> [sRGB] and [IEC-4WD]).
>
> Note 2: Almost all systems used today to view Web content assume sRGB
> encoding. Unless it is known that another color space will be used to
> process and display the content, authors should evaluate using sRGB
> colorspace. If using other color spaces, see Understanding Success
> Criterion 1.4.3.
>
> Note 3: If dithering occurs after delivery, then the source color
> value is used. For colors that are dithered at the source, the average
> values of the colors that are dithered should be used (average R,
> average G, and average B).
>
> Note 4: Tools are available that automatically do the calculations
> when testing contrast and flash.

Comment: Only checking the relative luminance doesn't account for opposite (or near opposite) colors which can also be difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub recently addressed this in a [blog post](https://github.blog/2022-06-14-accelerating-github-theme-creation-with-color-tooling/). There are issues with the WCAG color accessibility formulas, especially with light on dark text, which [their tool](https://primer.style/prism/) attempts to solve.

Comment: This is a tool, Is there a reference to the algorithm used to check if text is readable on a background? _(also, answers should be self contained, not linking to external links which may become invalid)_

Comment: @ideasman42 The tool links to it's [source code](https://github.com/primer/prism), as well as [a blog post](https://github.blog/2022-06-14-accelerating-github-theme-creation-with-color-tooling/) explaining how it works. Perhaps further investigation of this tool could be helpful to you. Some of the [further reading](https://programmingdesignsystems.com/color/perceptually-uniform-color-spaces/index.html) that blog links to discussing perceptually uniform color spaces is pretty interesting as well.

Comment: An answer shouldn't link to an answer, it should be self contained. From what I can see, the link can be reduced to the answer: **"Using colors that have a contrasting brightness (Luv) in HSLuv color-space has been shown to work well as a way to ensure text contrasts with it's background."** That github has a tool that uses the color space is an interesting reference but not exactly an  answer.